# Where is Shabbat 116b in the Munich Manuscript?

Tags: shabbat, talmud-bavli, manuscripts

Can someone please tell me on which folio to find Shabbat 116b in the Munich Manuscript?

My Hebrew is weak, and the numbering is different in the Munich Talmud:

https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb00003409?page=22,23

The index shows where Tractate Shabbat starts and ends, but it is far too difficult to read for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant one is [27v (0062)](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb00003409?page=62).

However, the different folios are more easily accessible through the manuscript tool in Sefaria. Here's a link to the relevant folio from the Munich 95 MS:

https://manuscripts.sefaria.org/munich-manuscript/munich-manuscript-95Cod.hebr.95pg.0062.jpg

As you can see from the text of the link, they use the same numbering for the folios, which makes it easy to track them down in the larger documents. To access folios in Sefaria, find the page you want to view and then click on manuscripts from the menu and choose the one you want.

You can likewise access text versions and images of that MS and of other talmudic MSS at the [Cairo Genizah website](https://fjms.genizah.org/ResponsivePortal.htm?eraseCache=true?eraseCache=true) (with a free sign up required).